# I have create table in oracle11g which has blob and clob data type and then I have run following query

Tags: oracle11g, schema, ddl

I am trying to create a sample program, that get ddl schema of any targeted database. I am using get_ddl() method to fetch such ddl sql. I have an issue that when I run `get_ddl` command for index like:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', INDEX_NAME) FROM USER_INDEXES ;
```

It returns all create index query in the result that also includes the following kind of index query -

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "SCOTT"."SYS_IL0000076778865$$" ON "SCOTT"."CLOBD" (
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
  PARALLEL (DEGREE 0 INSTANCES 0)
```

Such index query is auto generated by database for CLOB and BLOB datatype. 
So I want to ignore that queries from fetching ddl schema list
How can I ignore it? or suggest me the way to ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out index_types that are not required.

```
 SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('INDEX', INDEX_NAME) FROM USER_INDEXES WHERE INDEX_TYPE NOT IN ('LOB');
```

Here are the sample types:

SQL> select distinct index_type from dba_indexes;

### INDEX_TYPE

IOT - TOP

LOB

FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL

NORMAL

CLUSTER

Comment: Thanku .It is working.